# How can I find multiple values from windows command line output?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch

Example, to see if KB983590 is installed:

`systeminfo | find "KB983590"`

But what if I wanted to find out if more then one KB was installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
systeminfo | findstr "KB"
```

You can also use /i for case insensitive searching.  Run findstr /? for even more options.

If you want to search for just a subset of patches, use spaces in between entries:

```
systeminfo | findstr "KB958488 KB976902 KB976932"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a line like this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims= " %i IN (`netstat -ano ^|find "ESTABLISHED"`) DO @tasklist /fi "pid eq %i" | find "%i"
```

or, a bit shorter, this does the same:

```
netstat -a -b -n -o | findstr ESTABLISHED || tasklist | findstr PID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go the route of 'find' instead of 'findstr' (simpler/easier)

```
systeminfo | find /I "kb"
```

you'll get your list.

use for /f to organize the data easier such as

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %F IN ('systeminfo ^| find /I "kb"') DO ECHO %F%G%H
```

that will get rid of the numbered sequence from the beginning of each line.

if you want only the KB#####, change the tokens value to only 2 without the asterisk, and change the ending ECHO to just ECHO %F

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %F IN ('systeminfo ^| find /I "kb"') DO ECHO %F%G%H>>"%USERPROFILE%\desktop\systeminfo.txt"
```

will throw it on your desktop as a .TXT file

of course if you want it ina batch file, make sure your %F has an extra % (%%F)

Answer (score 0):

You could also join multiple commands using &&

```
setlocal
set USERNAME=rbrown
net user %USERNAME% /domain | Find /i "Full Name" && net user %USERNAME% /domain | Find /i "Password expires"
endlocal

Full Name                    Richard Brown
Password expires             8/04/2021 9:32:54 am
```